# Find the point of intersection of the straight line $\frac{X+1}{4}=\frac{Y-2}{-2}=\frac{Z+6}{7}$ and plane $3X+8Y-9Z=0$

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the point of intersection of the straight line 
$$\frac{X+1}{4}=\frac{Y-2}{-2}=\frac{Z+6}{7}$$ and plane $3X+8Y-9Z=0$

the point of the line is $M(-1,2,-6)$ and direction vector of the line is $A(4,-2,7)$

I would like to get some advice how to do that.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to say that the direction vector is $\langle 4, -2,7 \rangle$?

Comment: yes, fixed thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\frac {X+1}4 = \frac {Y-2}{-2} = \frac {Z+6}7 = k \\
X = 4k - 1 \\
Y = -2k + 2 \\
Z = 7k - 6
$$
Substitute it to the equation of plane
$$
3X+8Y-9Z = 0 \\
12k-3 - 16k + 16 - 63k + 54 = 0 \\
-67k + 67 = 0 \\
k = 1
$$
Since you know $k$, you can easily find $X,Y,Z$.
$$
X = 4k-1 = 3 \\
Y = -2k+2 = 0 \\
Z = 7k-6 = 1
$$
So, point of intersection is $(3,0,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Write all the parameters as one of them, say:

$$y=\frac{-x-1}2+2=\frac{-x+3}2\;,\;\;z=\frac{7x+7}4-6=\frac{7x-17}{4}$$

Substitute in the plane's formula:

$$3x+8\left(\frac{-x+3}2\right)-9\left(\frac{7x-17}4\right)=0\iff -\frac{67}4x+\frac{201}4=0\implies$$

$$ x=3\;,\;y=0\;,\;z=1$$

From here it follows that I've no idea what you call $\,M\,$ to as the intersection point between the given line and given plane is $\;(3,0,1)\;\ldots$